# How can I separate and coordinate spaces on HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a template HTML page which I wanna try out for a new HTML. Actually, I almost finished it but I couldn't fix space problem. I want to slide all columns to next of the another one that don't have any space. Because my description part is so long and I want to create more space on that area:

[image: Example for my html]

How can I coordinate these spaces with this code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logoDiv"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" /></div>
    <form id="search_toolbar" method="get" action="/solr/select">
        <input id="searchinput" type="text" name="q" value="search" size="28" maxlength="200" onfocus="searchBarOnFocus(this)" onblur="searchBarOnBlur(this)" /></form></div>
    </br>
</br>
<div id="tabcontainer"><div id="tabs" class="nav"><span><a id="navtab" href="#" class="btn">Navigation</a></span>
    <span><a id="searchtab" href="/solr/select" class="btn">Search</a></span>
    <span><a id="viewtab" href="#" class="btn-highlight">View</a></span>
    <span><a id="180DaysDocumentstab" class="btn"  >180 Days Documents</a></span>
</br>
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header"><h1 class="removeBottomPadding">
        </br>
        &nbsp; &nbsp; 180 Days Documents         
    </div>
</div><div id="dmApplicability"><h2 id="dmApplicabilityTitle" class="removeBottomPadding"></h2><p></p></div><h1></h1><ol class="steplevel0"><li><div id="d534007e87" class="step">

<div class="note"><h4 class="removeTopBottomPadding noteText">NOTE</h4>
    <div class="cautionText">This Documents Downloaded From ADDs Page/Last Revision Date : dd/mm/yy </div>
</div>
<div><table class="hoverRowBackEnabled setFixedHeaderEnabled"><thead><tr><th>
</div></li></ol></div><div class="legendDiv" id="legendDiv"><div id="legend-anchor">
<div id="legendWindow" class="legendWindow hide"></div></div></div>
<div id="scroller-anchor"></div><div id="scroller">                     
<div id="zoom_container"><div class="landmarks" data-show-at-zoom="100" data-allow-drag="false"></div></div><h3 id="canvas-title"></h3></div></div></div></div>
</div>
<div class="tirDIV"></div>

<table id="userdata" border="2">

    <th>Revision  Date </th>
    <th>Document  Name </th>
    <th>Department </th>
    <th>Description </th>

</table>
<script> 
$.each(data.person, function(i, person) {
    var tblRow =  

    "<tr><td>" + person.revisiondate +
    "</td><td><a target='_blank' href='"+ person.documentname.split('href=')[0]+"' >"+person.documentname.split('href=')[0]+"</a></td>"+
    "<td>" + person.department +
    "</td><td>" + person.description + "</td></tr>"

    $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a correct behavior for a table.

You can add a minimum width for your last row with something like :

```
<script> 
 $.each(data.person, function(i, person) {
            var tblRow =  

"<tr><td>" + person.revisiondate +
"</td><td><a target='_blank' href='"+ person.documentname.split('href=')[0]+"' >"+person.documentname.split('href=')[0]+"</a></td>"+
"<td>" + person.department +
"</td><td style="min-width: 50%;">" + person.description + "</td></tr>"

            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
        });

</script>
```

But it would be better within a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem's solving with some people's help. Thank you. On html, if you using  and  tag. you can cordinate width and height. Like,

```
<table id="userdata" border="2">

            <th width="12%"> Revision  Date </th>
            <th width="12%">Document  Name </th>
            <th width="12%">Department </th>
            <th width="40%">&nbsp; Description</th>

    </table>
```

That I want to do,

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BowZB.jpg)

Source ; https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp